# Difficulty in starting client in spring boot microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

In spring boot microservice whole of application is getting compiled properly. When I run eureka server also is being run successfully. Problem starts when I run a client application. The error that is coming in server is as follows

org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.selectImports(GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.java:46) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:586) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
26 common frames omitted

---

i am not able to post error and all details such as pom.xml and application.properties file contents

main error seems to be as  follows

java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Comment: As I can understand from logs, you have something wrong with configuration, check it.

Comment: Whole configuration is checked, looks fine only.

Comment: What all dependencies are needed in pom.xml???